# text box Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- I am trying to implement a twitter box in react.
- but I am getting an error.
  Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined
- can you guys tell me how to fix it.
- providing it below.

https://jsfiddle.net/q7yvmsa3/4/

```or-tag-here
class TwitterBox extends React.component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { enteredTextBoxvalue : '' };

    }

    // var textBoxValue = textbox.value();

    // var totalCount = textBoxValue.count();

    // if (totalCount > 140) {

    //  div.addCSS{ border: 1px solid red}

    // }


    render() {
        return (<div>Hello {this.props.name}
                        <textarea value = "this.state.enteredTextBoxvalue">
                            there should be only 140 characters
                    </textarea>
        </div>);
    }



}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: You have a typo at React.component (should be capital C)

Comment: You had three errors on your code. I fixed them at: https://jsfiddle.net/q7yvmsa3/7/

Comment: @zvona it would be great if you explain what you fixed it...so that in future I will do it myself

Comment: @texirv please accept one of these answers, by ticking the green checkmark to either's left, as the problems here have been solved.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier why its made negative??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes:

**1.** Typo in `React.component`, it should be `React.Component`.

**2.** Dynamic value must be inside `{}` but you defined it as string: `value = "this.state.enteredTextBoxvalue"` it should be `value = {this.state.enteredTextBoxvalue}`

**3.** You defined the name of component as `TwitterBox`, but rendering `Hello`:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Hello/>,....)
```

**4.** You are using the [controlled component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) (means defined the value property of `textarea`), so define a `onChange` function also, and update the value of `state` variable inside that.

**5.** Don't define the children of `textarea`, if you want some default value then initial the `state` value by that.

Check the working example:

```js
class TwitterBox extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { enteredTextBoxvalue : '' };
      this.change = this.change.bind(this);
    }
    
    change(e){
       this.setState({enteredTextBoxvalue: e.target.value}); 
    }
    
    render() {
       return (
          <div>
              Hello {this.props.name}
              <textarea value={this.state.enteredTextBoxvalue} onChange={this.change}/>
          </div>
       )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <TwitterBox name='hello'/>,       
   document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='container'/>
```

Comment: hello can you tell me why we are passing e inside change, without that cant we get the value of the text box....had this question so many times...but not able to find it  :(

Comment: e is nothing but a event object, we are not passing that, it will get passed automatically in change method, it will contains all the info about that element, check the MDN doc about more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Comment: hey is there any diagram representation...its confusing :(

Answer (score 1):

You had three errors on your code. See https://jsfiddle.net/q7yvmsa3/7/ for (kind of) working result.

1. It's `React.Component` with capital C
2. You added component `Hello`, although your component is called `TwitterBox`
3. You refer to `this.state.enteredTextBoxvalue` inside quotes (making it as string), but it should be refered in brackets.

And additional note: you need to update **enteredTextBoxvalue** state on every keypress in order to keep textarea in sync.